# How to filter data from list using seachview and action bar

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, searchview

I have been trying to implement a Search-view in action bar using list-view. My
project contains a list-view with a custom adapter which is extends by
Array-adapter. I fetched data from dataHelper class. I have model class which is contain name and phone fields. How I filter list-view using name.
`MainActivity`

```
private ActionBar actionBar;
    private ListView listView;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    ArrayList<Personinfo> list;
    ArrayAdapter<Personinfo> arrayAdapter;
    AdapterFilter adapterfilter;
    Personinfo personinfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
                .parseColor("#03A9F4")));
        actionBar.setTitle("Agarwal Association");
        list = new ArrayList<Personinfo>();
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        csvToSqlite();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        getlistData();
        adapterfilter = new AdapterFilter(this, R.layout.child_listview, list);
        // adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
        Log.i("List", "" + list.get(0).getPhoneno());
        listView.setAdapter(adapterfilter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        synchronized (listView) {
            listView.notify();
            // }
        }
        // final TextView txtviewnumber = (TextView)
        // findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void getlistData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getData();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name"));
            String phoneNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PhoneNo"));
            Personinfo personinfo = new Personinfo(name, phoneNo);
            list.add(personinfo);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();

    }

    public void csvToSqlite() {
        try {
            String reader = "";
            boolean skipheader = true;
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.raw.agrawalsurnamedata);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));
            while ((reader = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // skip header column name from csv
                if (skipheader) {
                    skipheader = false;
                    continue;
                }
                String[] RowData = reader.split(",");
                if (databaseHelper.insertContact(RowData) == true) {
                    Log.i("inside csvToSqlite()", " data inserted successfully");
                } else {
                    Log.i("inside csvToSqlite()",
                            " data is not inserted into db");
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                adapterfilter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                adapterfilter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

`AdapterFilter`

```
public class AdapterFilter extends ArrayAdapter<Personinfo> {
    ArrayList<Personinfo> list = new ArrayList<Personinfo>();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AdapterFilter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<Personinfo> list) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Personinfo getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_listview, parent,
                    false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final Personinfo personinfo = (Personinfo) getItem(position);
        viewHolder.txtName.setText(personinfo.getName());
        viewHolder.txtPhone.setText(personinfo.getPhoneno());
        viewHolder.imageButtonCalling.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // Calling on selected number
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "number button Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String selectedChildPhone = personinfo.getPhoneno();
                String phoneNo = "tel:" + selectedChildPhone.trim();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNo));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        viewHolder.imageButtonMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // Sending sms to whatsapp
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "meesaage button Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String selectedChildPhone = personinfo.getPhoneno();
                Uri mUri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + selectedChildPhone);
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                smsIntent.setType("text/plain");
                smsIntent.putExtra("address", mUri);
                smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "your desired message");
                context.startActivity(smsIntent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName, txtPhone;
        ImageButton imageButtonCalling, imageButtonMessage;

        public ViewHolder(View item) {
            txtName = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            txtPhone = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
            imageButtonCalling = (ImageButton) item
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCalling);
            imageButtonMessage = (ImageButton) item
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageButtonMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

`Personinfo.java`

```
public class Personinfo {
    private String name;
    private String phoneno;
    public Personinfo(String name, String phoneno) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public  String getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }
    public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }   
}
```

I am trying like that but listview not filtering by name. Where is my mistake please suggest me!!!
Thanks

Comment: if my answer works pls accept it

Answer (score 0):

Implement getFilter() method in your custom adapter which filter your listview according to search query. You have to implement Filterable interface for your searching functionality

```
public class AdapterFilter extends ArrayAdapter<Personinfo> implements Filterable{
    ArrayList<Personinfo> list = new ArrayList<Personinfo>();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ArrayList<Personinfo> orig;

    public AdapterFilter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<Personinfo> list) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Personinfo getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_listview, parent,
                    false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final Personinfo personinfo = (Personinfo) getItem(position);
        viewHolder.txtName.setText(personinfo.getName());
        viewHolder.txtPhone.setText(personinfo.getPhoneno());
        viewHolder.imageButtonCalling.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // Calling on selected number
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "number button Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String selectedChildPhone = personinfo.getPhoneno();
                String phoneNo = "tel:" + selectedChildPhone.trim();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNo));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        viewHolder.imageButtonMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // Sending sms to whatsapp
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "meesaage button Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String selectedChildPhone = personinfo.getPhoneno();
                Uri mUri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + selectedChildPhone);
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                smsIntent.setType("text/plain");
                smsIntent.putExtra("address", mUri);
                smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "your desired message");
                context.startActivity(smsIntent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }



@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<Personinfo> results = new ArrayList<Personinfo>();
                if (orig == null) {
                    orig = list;
                }
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Personinfo g : orig) {
                            if (g.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(constraint.toString())) {
                                results.add(g);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = list;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                list = (ArrayList<Personinfo>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName, txtPhone;
        ImageButton imageButtonCalling, imageButtonMessage;

        public ViewHolder(View item) {
            txtName = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            txtPhone = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
            imageButtonCalling = (ImageButton) item
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCalling);
            imageButtonMessage = (ImageButton) item
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageButtonMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: okay, but getFilter() method already inbuilt in ArrayAdapter class so why implement this method in adapter class. I already extends this custom adapter by ArrayAdapter so??

Answer (score 0):

Here my sample code, hope this help

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {
    ...  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        if (listAdapter != null) {
            listAdapter.filterData("");
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (listAdapter != null) {
            listAdapter.filterData(query);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (listAdapter != null) {
            listAdapter.filterData(newText);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public void filterData(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        mList.clear();

        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            mList.addAll(mList_original);
        } else {
            for (String header : mList_original) {
                if (header.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                    mList.add(header);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```